Stuck on the formal derivation of the $ \vec v = \dot r\hat r + r \dot\theta\hat \theta $ formula for velocity in polar coordinates
I'm trying to derive the formula for the velocity of a particle in $ \mathbb R^2 $ in polar coordinates using the framework of differential geometry (charts, tangent vectors, etc.), just to familiarize with this language. (Next step will be to derive the formula for the acceleration by computing some Christoffel symbols).
Consider the manifold $ M = \mathbb R^2\setminus\{x\leqq 0\} $ (i.e., the plane minus the non-positive horizontal semiaxis).
On $ M $ we can put the standard (Cartesian) coordinates $ (x,y) $ or the familiar polar coordinates $ (r,\theta) $. Given $ p\in M $, denote with $ \partial/\partial x\rvert_p $, $ \partial/\partial y\rvert_p $ the basis of $ \mathrm T_pM $ induced by the Cartesian coordinates, and with $ \partial/\partial r\rvert_p $, $ \partial/\partial\theta\rvert_p $ the basis of $ \mathrm T_pM $ induced by the polar ones.
A simple calculation shows that
$$
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right\rvert_p = \cos\theta(p)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right\rvert_p + \sin\theta(p)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right\rvert_p\text{,}\qquad \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right\rvert_p = -\sin\theta(p)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right\rvert_p + \cos\theta(p)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right\rvert_p
$$
i.e. that the change of basis matrix $ A_{\mathrm{Cartesian}\to\mathrm{Polar}}(p) $ for $ \mathrm T_pM $ is given by
$$
A_{\mathrm{Cartesian}\to\mathrm{Polar}}(p) = R(\theta(p))
$$
where $ R(\theta(p)) $ is the rotation matrix in dimension $ 2 $. We can easily reverse the operation:
$$
A_{\mathrm{Polar}\to\mathrm{Cartesian}}(p) = R(-\theta(p))
$$
since $ R(\theta(p))^{-1} = R(-\theta(p)) $.
Now, take a curve $ \gamma\colon \mathbb R\to M $. I want to express the velocity vector $ \dot\gamma(t)\in \mathrm T_{\gamma(t)}M $ of $ \gamma $ at the time $ t $ in polar coordinates, and derive the formula
$$
\dot\gamma(t) = r(\gamma (t))^\prime \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right\rvert_{\gamma(t)} + r(\gamma(t))\theta(\gamma(t))^\prime \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right\rvert_{\gamma(t)}\label{formula}\tag{$ * $}
$$
usually seen in freshman Mechanics textbooks. If I'm not mistaken, I can proceed like this. I'll put $ p = \gamma(t) $ in the following.
I can write
$$
\dot\gamma(t) = \dot\gamma^1(t)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right\rvert_p + \dot\gamma^2(t)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right\rvert_p = v^1\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right\rvert_p + v^2\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right\rvert_p
$$
where $ \dot\gamma^i(t) $ is just the derivative of the $ i $-th component of $ \gamma $ seen as a curve in $ \mathbb R^2 $, and at this point I have two ways of calculating the $ v^i $s.
I can go on like in
$$
v^i = \dot{\tilde\gamma}(t)
$$
where $ \tilde\gamma^i(t) = (r,\theta)\circ \gamma(t) $ and $ (r,\theta)\colon M\to \left]0,+\infty\right[\times \left]-\pi,\pi\right[ $ is the polar chart.
Or I can just do a change of coordinates like in
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v^1\\
v^2
\end{bmatrix} = R(-\theta(p))
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot\gamma^1(t)\\
\dot\gamma^2(t)
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}
$$
My problem is that neither way gives me the desired result $ \eqref{formula} $.

A very good exercise. Ben's terse answer pointed out that the Cartesian and polar bases are related by
\begin{align}
\partial_r&=(\cos\theta),\partial_x+(\sin\theta),\partial_x\
\partial_\theta&=-{\color{red}r},(\sin\theta),\partial_x+{\color{red}r},(\cos\theta),\partial_y,.
\end{align}
The Riemannian metric is
$$
\boldsymbol{g}=dx\otimes dx+dy\otimes dy=dr\otimes dr+\color{red}{r^2}d\theta\otimes d\theta,.
$$

You should check that the vector
$$
\boldsymbol{v}=v^x\partial_x+v^y\partial_y=v^r\partial_r+v^\theta\partial_\theta
$$
has the same length squared $\boldsymbol{g}(\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{v})$ regardless in which coordinate system we express $\boldsymbol{g}$ and $\boldsymbol{v},.$

I don't get why you and @Volk are referring to the metric. In my understanding the formula for $ \dot\gamma(t) $ in the polar basis should not depend on metric considerations (i.e. to write $ \dot\gamma(t) = v^1\partial_r + v^2\partial_\theta $ from $ \dot\gamma(t) = \dot\gamma^1(t)\partial_x + \dot\gamma^2(t)\partial_y $ it should be sufficient to do a basic change of basis).

If I'm not mistaken (again), the change of basis matrix from Cartesian to polar should be
$$
A_{\mathrm{Polar}\to\mathrm{Cartesian}}(p) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\
0 & 1/r(p)
\end{pmatrix}
R(-\theta(p))
$$
but I probably am since this does not give me the desired result (I did the calculation in my head and I'll check it again when I'll be back home).

Three contributors have now pointed out the factor $\color{red}{r}$ that you were missing in the angle transformation. What this has to do with the metric is elaborated on here.

Excuse me @Kurt, but based on your suggestions
$$
A_{\mathrm{Polar}\to\mathrm{Cartesian}}(p) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta(p) & -r(p)\sin\theta(p)\
\sin\theta(p) & r(p)\cos\theta(p)
\end{pmatrix}
R(\theta(p))
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\
0 & r(p)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so that it's inverse (i.e. the change of basis matrix from Cartesian to polar) is exactly what I wrote above.

My suggestion is the chain rule from which the two equations in my first comment follow. Firstly: I do not want to be credited for having invented that and secondly I am of the opinion that 90% of basic differential geometry can be derived from it (tangent vectors, pullbacks, pushforwards, and what not). Therefore I congratulated you to be on the right track. In my notation Polar$\to$ Cartesian is \begin{align}\partial_x&=(\cos\theta),\partial_r-\tfrac1r(\sin\theta),\partial_\theta\\partial_y&=(\sin\theta),\partial_r+\tfrac1r(\cos\theta),\partial_\theta,.\end{align}

I don't see the formula in the last comment  being compliant with this but perhaps I just don't understand your notation.

Given that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_r &= \cos\theta, \partial_x + \sin\theta, \partial_y\
\partial_\theta &= -r\sin\theta, \partial_x + r\cos\theta, \partial_y
\end{aligned}
$$
the change of basis matrix form polar to Cartesian is
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -r\sin\theta\
\sin\theta & r\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\
0 & r
\end{pmatrix}\text{.}
$$
(Continued)

It's inverse $ A^{-1} $ is the change of basis matrix from Cartesian to polar. We obtain
$$
A^{-1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\
0 & r
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\
0 & 1/r
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(-\theta) & -\sin(-\theta)\
\sin(-\theta) & \cos(-\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where
$$
\cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta\text{,}\qquad \sin(-\theta) = -\sin\theta\text{.}
$$
(Continued)

In this way we obtain
$$
A^{-1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta\
-\frac1r\sin\theta & \frac1r\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is exactly your result.
Now, I don't know if it was clear from my question, but what I am really asking is how form the expression
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_x &= \cos\theta, \partial_r - \frac1r \sin\theta\
\partial_y &= \sin\theta, \partial_r + \frac1r\cos\theta
\end{aligned}
$$
we can derive eqn (*) I wrote on the original question.

There's a typo in the last comment: it should be
$$
\begin{aligned} \partial_x &= \cos\theta, \partial_r - \frac1r \sin\theta,\partial_y\ \partial_y &= \sin\theta, \partial_r + \frac1r\cos\theta,\partial_y\text{.}\end{aligned}
$$

Too long for a comment. Your (*) looks weird.
We know
\begin{align}
x&=r\cos\theta\,,&y&=r\sin\theta\,.
\end{align}
Thus, one and the same curve $\gamma(t)$ can be expressed either way
$$
\gamma(t)=\pmatrix{x\\y}(t)=\pmatrix{r\cos\theta\\r\sin\theta}(t)\,.
$$
(I pull out the $(t)$ in favour of writing $r(t)\cos(\theta(t))$ etc.)
Likewise, a function $f(x,y)$ can be expressed in polar coordinates as
$$
f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=g(r,\theta)\,.
$$
The chain rule gives
\begin{align}
\partial_rg&=(\partial_xf)(\cos\theta)+(\partial_yf)(\sin\theta)\,,\\[2mm]
\partial_\theta g&=(\partial_xf)(-r\sin\theta)+(\partial_yf)(r\cos\theta)\,.
\end{align}
This leads to the transformation of the Cartesian coordinate basis $\{\partial_x,\partial_y\}$ to the polar coordinate basis $\{\partial_r,\partial_\theta\}$ which seems clear to you now.
Similarly we have by the chain rule
$$
\frac d{dt}f(\gamma(t))=(\partial_xf)\,\dot x(t)+(\partial_xf)\,\dot y(t)\,.
$$
This shows that the tangent vector to the curve $\gamma(t)$ at $p=\gamma(t)$ is
in Cartesian coordinates
$$\tag1
\dot x(t)\,\partial_x+\dot y(t)\,\partial_y\,.
$$
In polar coordinates we get it from
$$
\frac d{dt}g(\gamma(t))=(\partial_rg)\,\dot r(t)+(\partial_\theta g)\,\dot \theta(t)
$$
as
$$\tag2
\dot r(t)\,\partial_r+\dot\theta(t)\,\partial_\theta\,.
$$
Since
\begin{align}
\dot x&=\dot r\cos\theta-r(\sin\theta)\dot\theta\,,\\[2mm]
\dot y&=\dot r\sin\theta+r(\cos\theta)\dot\theta\,
\end{align}
we can plug into (1) and get
\begin{align}
\dot x\,\partial_x+\dot y\,\partial_y&=(\dot r\cos\theta-r(\sin\theta)\dot\theta)\,\partial_x+
(\dot r\sin\theta+r(\cos\theta)\dot\theta)\,\partial_y\\
&=\dot r\underbrace{(\cos\theta\,\partial_x+\sin\theta\,\partial_y)}_{\textstyle\partial_r}
+\dot\theta\underbrace{(-r\sin\theta\,\partial_x+r\cos\theta\,\partial_y)}_{\textstyle\partial_\theta}
\end{align}
which shows that (1) and (2) are one and the same tangent vector.
To summarize: It all follows from the chain rule and your (*) should look
more like (2).
About the notation in the title: we discussed the metric in polar coordinates by which the vector $\partial_\theta$ is not normalized. It has length $r\,.$
The normalized basis vectors are $\hat r=\partial_r,\hat\theta=\frac1r\partial_\theta\,.$ This turns (2) into
$$
\vec v=\dot r\,\hat r+r\,\dot\theta\,\hat\theta
$$
as expected.

I think that at this point I really have a more clear understanding about what's going on. I posted an answer describing my doubts and how I overcame them based on the answers/comments there for the benefit of posterity. Than you (and to all the other members) c:

The simple calculation is incorrect; the matrix is not a rotation. Check:
$$\partial_\theta = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\partial_x + \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\partial_y = -r\sin\theta \partial_x + r\cos\theta\partial_y$$

Let radial vector: $\vec r=r\hat r=r(\cos\theta\hat i+\sin\theta\hat j)$,
and unit tangential vector: $\hat\theta=-\sin\theta\hat i+\cos\theta\hat j$ (rotation of the unit radial vector $\hat r$ by $90^\circ$ ccw).
Observe that $\hat\theta=\frac{\mathrm d\hat r}{\mathrm d\theta}$.
Now, by the product rule:
$$\Large \color{red}{\vec v=\frac{\mathrm d\vec r}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt}\hat r+r\frac{\mathrm d\hat r}{\mathrm d\theta}\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt}=\dot r\hat r+r\dot\theta\hat\theta}$$
If we differentiate $\vec v$ with respect to time $t$, we get the acceleration that includes centrifugal, Coriolis and Euler components.

I confused from the start the vector $ \hat\theta $ from vector calculus with the vector $ \partial_\theta $. The relation between the two in our framework is
$$
\hat\theta = \frac1r\partial_\theta\text{.}
$$
Now, the relation I was trying to prove, namely
$$
\dot\gamma(t) = r(\gamma (t))^\prime \partial_r + r(\gamma(t))\theta(\gamma(t))^\prime \partial_\theta
$$
is actually false. What really holds is that
$$
\dot\gamma(t) = r(\gamma(t))^\prime \partial_r + \theta(\gamma(t))^\prime \partial_\theta
$$
but this is obvious!
What's really interesting in the (correct) change-of-basis formulae
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_r &=\cos\theta\,\partial_x + \sin\theta\,\partial_x\\
\partial_\theta &=-r\sin\theta\,\partial_x + r\cos\theta\, \partial_y \end{align}
$$
is the fact that we can go from the polar coordinate expression
$$
\dot\gamma(t) = r(\gamma(t))^\prime \partial_r + \theta(\gamma(t))^\prime \partial_\theta
$$
to the Cartesian one
$$
\dot\gamma(t) = x(\gamma(t))^\prime \partial_x + y(\gamma(t))^\prime \partial_y
$$
and back just multiplying by some change-of-basis matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot\gamma^x\\
\dot\gamma^y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta(p) & -r(p)\sin\theta(p)\\
\sin\theta(p) & r(p)\cos\theta(p)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot\gamma^r\\
\dot\gamma^\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot\gamma^r\\
\dot\gamma^\theta
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
-\frac1r\sin\theta & \frac1r\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot\gamma^x\\
\dot\gamma^y
\end{pmatrix}\text{.}
$$
The point is this: I thought that
$$
\vec v = \dot r\hat r + r\dot\theta \hat\theta
$$
was some obscure formula that had to be derived from some change-of-basis computation. Now I understand that it nothing but the usual
$$
\dot\gamma(t) = \dot\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu
$$
where one of the $\partial_\mu $s has been substituted with $ \frac1r\partial_\mu $.
